# Can I load images dynamically using React.Componet's props and "require() function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanted to load images in MyButton class dynamically.
so, I added the "imgpath" tag in "MyButton" and coded the following in render fuction in "MyButton" class.

```
var icon = require(this.props.imgpath);
```

But, error was founded the following .... for building.

> "Invalid call at line 32: require(this.props.imgpath)  Failed building
>   JavaScript bundle."

But `alert(this.props.imgpath)` was exactly printed "imgpath" tag!

What's the problem? And how can I do?
Thank you.

```
// ButtonGroup Class
export default class ButtonGroup extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.buttongroup}>
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <MyButton name="account" imgpath='/img/account.png' />
                    <MyButton name="friends" imgpath='/img/friends.png'/>
                    <MyButton name="lecture" imgpath='/img/lecture.png'/>
                    <MyButton name="calc" imgpath='/img/calc.png'/>
                </View>
                <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <MyButton name="message" imgpath='/img/message.png'/>
                    <MyButton name="list" imgpath='/img/list.png'/>
                    <MyButton name="help" imgpath='/img/help.png'/>
                    <MyButton name="config" imgpath='/img/config.png'/>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

// MyButton Class
class MyButton extends Component {
    render() {
        // No.1 SUCCESS
        //var icon = require('../../img/star.png');

        //alert(this.props.imgpath);   is OK
        // No.2 but this code was FAILED
        var icon = require(this.props.imgpath);

        return (
            <View style={{flex:1, height:100, borderWidth: 0.5}}>
                <Image source={icon} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
                <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Error Message is the following...

> Invalid call at line 32: require(this.props.imgpath) Failed building
>   JavaScript bundle.

Comment: Import the images in `MyButton` class and pass the name of it as props.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky workaround here is to pass f.e require('../../img/star.png') as a prop instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

try to send like this;

```
            <MyButton
                imagePath={require('yourPath')}
                onPress={()=> {}}/>
```

and set here that inside myButton component

```
<Image 
   style={{}} 
   resizeMode={""}
   source={this.props.imagePath}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [React Native Documentation says](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html), all your images sources need to be loaded before compiling your bundle. So on your button component, you can leave it like this:

```js
class MyButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, height:100, borderWidth: 0.5}}>
        <Image source={this.props.imgpath} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
          <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and then where you are using `<MyButton/>` component you can do:

```js
<View style={{ flex:1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <MyButton name="message" imgpath={require('/img/message.png')}/>
  <MyButton name="list" imgpath={require('/img/list.png')}/>
  <MyButton name="help" imgpath={require('/img/help.png')}/>
  <MyButton name="config" imgpath={require('/img/config.png')}/>
</View>
```

but personally I would do something like this:

**MyButton.js**

```js
/** Import all the images you need **/
import message from '/img/message.png';
import list from '/img/list.png';
import config from '/img/config.png';

class MyButton extends Component {
  renderImage() {
     let icon = message; // default

     switch(this.props.name) {
       case 'message':
         return message;
       case 'list':
         return list;
       default:
         return config;
     }

     return <Image source={icon} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex:1, height:100, borderWidth: 0.5}}>
          {this.renderImage()}
          <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

then you can use it like this:

```js
<MyButton name="config"/>
```

Comment: Wow!!! Your solution worked very well and Thank you very much for solving my troubles.